# ReSharper make C++ IntelliSense warnings vanish

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resharper, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

Been played by subtleties of C++ references, wondering why code wouldn't behave as expected.

Someone versed in C++ pointed out what the actual error was: the lack of using a reference.

The actual warning shown by IntelliSense is:

> *'auto' doesn't deduce references, A possibly unintended copy is being made.*

After fiddling with settings, turns out that ReSharper is at fault.

When project is opening and ReSharper hasn't yet loaded, squiggles are visible:

[image]

As soon as ReSharper is loaded, the IntelliSense warning disappears:

[image]

Disabling ReSharper immediately fixes the problem, tried adjusting settings but no luck.

**Question:**

Is there an option in ReSharper that could cause the problem?

Comment: which version of visual-studio / variant are you using? visual studio proper? visual studio code? community? sorry to ask and it wont help me but from watching other similar questions related to C++ intellisense config it seems to matter. I can't see those images dues to firewall so I won't be able to help much further.  But if the code compiles without errors or warnings I wonder what the squiggles were even trying to complain about. Good luck!

Comment: Perhaps the errors in the error list window only appear after compilation?

Comment: This is not intellisense, this is the enabled code analysis.

Comment: It is *'auto' doesn't deduce references. A possibly unintended copy is being made.* Made some progress, the culprit is ReSharper! As soon as it gets disabled, warnings are back and visible... Latest version isn't any better. I think I'm good for reporting a bug.

Comment: @273K I tried enabling code analysis in project settings, R# is definitely the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try turning off "Hide all Visual Studio squiggles" and "Hide only those Visual Studio squiggles that duplicate ReSharper code analysis highlightings" on the "ReSharper | Options | Environment | Editor | Visual Studio Features" page. The relevant bug report is [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-492566).
[image]

Comment: That worked, thanks a bunch :)